# WinApi MoveFile - корректное слияние двух папок

Tags: c++, файлы, winapi

Подскажите как корректно слить две папки.

Я хочу переименовать папку `folder2` в `folder1`, но если `folder1` уже существует, хочу чтобы все файлы из папки `folder2` были перенесены в папку `folder1`, а папка `folder2` была бы удалена.

Если в Проводнике сделать это руками, то все работает так я описал выше, а что будет, если использовать WinAPI функцию MoveFile?

Comment: [MoveFileEx](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefileexa) смотрите внимательно раздел флагов.

Comment: проверил флаги - эффекта 0